# Flex 4.5 for mobile : Zooming on high resolution image

Tags: ipad, air, flash-builder, flex-mobile

I am trying to integrate a zoom/pan capability into an image gallery for iPad (implemented with Flash builder 4.5 and Air mobile sdk), which is pretty simple on the paper, using gesturezoom handling and scale on the displayed image.

My problem is that I have some medium & high resolution images (about 4096*3072, 5Mo photo), and that zoom/unzoom seems to freeze a lot on the iPad upon the first initial gestures. After a while, everything goes smooth (or kind of smooth :-).

Does anybody know what is the reason of these freezes, and how to solve this?

Thanks a lot,

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest working with the `BitmapData` of the image and blit to a container the size of the screen. The `Matrix` class can help you to scale the `BitmapData` you are drawing to your container and you can change the size of a `Rectangle` as your scaling gesture events occur to bring in more pixels from the source image. That way you're never displaying more than the amount of pixels that fit into your container at any given time.